# Tailwind CLI not importing external files

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS 3.0 and have configured it according to the [Using with Preprocessors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors) documentation.

My `main.css` file looks like this:

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "./custom-base-styles.css";

@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "./custom-components.css";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

My `postcss.config.js` looks like this:

```json
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
Styles/v2
├── custom-base-styles.css
├── custom-components.css
└── main.css
wwwroot/dev
└── v2
    └── main.css
```

And I execute the following command to build my `main.css` file:

```sh
npx tailwindcss -i ./Styles/v2/main.css -o ./wwwroot/dev/v2/main.css --watch
```

The build is executed and my `wwwroot/dev/v2/main.css` file is produced, but none of the additional changes added in my custom styles are included. Also; the `--watch` argument is listening for changes to the `main.css` input file, but non of the `@import`-ed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't actually using PostCSS directly when using `npx tailwindcss`. As explained on the [Tailwind CSS Getting Started](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) guide, Tailwind CLI and PostCSS are two different ways of using Tailwind.

So in the above question, the answer is to use [PostCSS CLI](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli) and invoke the build using: `postcss ./Styles/v2/main.css -o style.css --watch`.

Answer (score 2):

This should also do the trick!

```
tailwindcss -i ./Styles/v2/main.css -o style.css --postcss
```